# Testing sagas dependent on IBus using SagaFixture

Tags: rebus

What approach should I take if I want to test a saga using

```
 using(var fixture = SagaFixture.For<CollectLegalInfoSaga>())
    {
        // perform test in here
    }
```

The saga relies on an IBus instance beeing injected (either constructor or property. If the Bus property is null, one or more handlers in the saga will fail.

```
public class CollectLegalInfoSaga : Saga<CollectLegalInfoSagaData>,
      IAmInitiatedBy<CustomerCreated>,
      IHandleMessages<LegalInfoAcquiredInFirstSystem>,
      IHandleMessages<LegalInfoAcquiredInSecondSystem>
    {
        public IBus Bus {get;set;}

    }
```

As far as I can see the [SagaFixture](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Testing/SagaFixture.cs) wrapps the _activator which holds reference to an instance of a IBus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do something like this:

```
// this one implements IBus
var fakeBus = new FakeBus();

using(var fixture = SagaFixture.For(() => new CollectLegalInfoSaga(fakeBus)))
{
    // dispatch message(s) to saga here by calling
    // fixture.Deliver(message);
    // 
    // (....)
    //
    // assert that certain things have happened
    var sentRequests = fakeBus.Events
        .OfType<MessageSent<GetLegaInfoRequest>>()
        .ToList();

    Assert.That(sentRequests.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));

    var actualRequest = sentRequests.Single().CommandMessage;

    Assert.That(request.LegalEntityId, Is.EqualTo("wwwwhatever"));
}
```

That is,

1. Create `FakeBus` which is an `IBus` implementation that collects `FakeBusEvent`s in the form of `MessageSent<TCommandMessage>`, `MessagePublished<TEventMessage>`, etc.
2. Pass factory method to `SagaFixture` and inject your `FakeBus` instance
3. Check that the expected things were done to the `FakeBus`

The `IBus` instance within `SagaFixture` is not accessible because it is only used in order to provide the most realistic environment for passing messages to your saga – in fact, it IS a fully functioning bus instance that just happens to run on in-mem implementations of transport, saga persister, etc.